# Scroll-pane CSS not working for scroll-bars JavaFx2.2

Tags: css, javafx-2

here is the fxml for my Scrollpane which is in GridPane

```
    <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style=".scroll-pane .track{-fx-opacity: 0;}&#10;.scroll-pane .scroll-bar{-fx-base: transparent;}" vbarPolicy="AS_NEEDED" styleClass="myscrollpane" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
  <content>
  </content>
  <GridPane.margin>
    <Insets top="10.0" />
  </GridPane.margin>
</ScrollPane>
```

And the CSS i want to apply to it is

```
.myscrollpane .scroll-bar:horizontal ,
.myscrollpane  .scroll-bar:vertical{
-fx-background-color:#d7dddd; 

}
.myscrollpane .increment-button ,
.myscrollpane .decrement-button {
-fx-background-color:transparent;
-fx-background-radius: 0em;
-fx-padding:0 0.5 0 0;

}
.mylistview  .scroll-bar .increment-arrow,
.mylistview  .scroll-bar .decrement-arrow {
-fx-shape: " ";
-fx-padding:0;
}
.myscrollpane .scroll-bar:horizontal .track ,
.myscrollpane .scroll-bar:vertical .track{
-fx-background-color: transparent;
-fx-border-color:derive(gray,80%);
-fx-background-radius: 0em;
}

.myscrollpane .scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb,
.myscrollpane .scroll-bar:vertical .thumb {

-fx-background-color : #989898;
-fx-background-insets: 1, 0, 0;
-fx-background-radius: 0em;

}
.myscrollpane .scroll-bar:horizontal:hover .track ,
.myscrollpane .scroll-bar:horizontal:pressed .track ,
.myscrollpane .scroll-bar:vertical:hover .track,
.myscrollpane .scroll-bar:vertical:pressed .track{
-fx-background-color: derive(#434343,20%);
-fx-opacity: 0.2;
-fx-background-radius: 0em;

}
.myscrollpane .scroll-bar .thumb:hover,
.myscrollpane .scroll-bar .thumb:pressed{
-fx-background-color: derive(black,50%);
}
```

With myscrllpane is the class for Scroll-pane.
but it is not working in any mean. i.e directly writing the css in the fxml or by using url to embed CSS. As i must required this to be applied on the scrollbars of Scroll-pane.

Comment: You can't specify css selectors in the style attribute, only rules (i.e. you can't do style=".scroll-bar .track {...}", you can only do things like style="-fx-opacity: 0"). But, when I tested this, the external stylesheet worked fine. Are you sure you are applying the stylesheet correctly?

Comment: @James_D thanks james Working fine now as the url of style sheet was not correct so ur comment is helpful as it makes me think to embed the style sheet correctly.